# It is possible to use one route with two functions in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

```
Route::get('post/form/{id}', array('as' => 'admin.post.delete', 'uses' => "PostController@deleteForm"));

Route::get('post/form', array('as' => 'admin.post.create', 'uses' => "PostController@createForm"));
```

I want to combine two routes above in a route for two functions, create and delete. Because the both routes have only different `id`.

```
Route::get('post/form/{id}', array('as' => 'admin.post', 'uses' => "PostController@getForm"));
```

If I want to type without `id`, it redirects to create function. If I type with `id`, it redirect to delete function.

How can I use one route for two functions?

Comment: What you are wanting to do is quite impractical, could you not just update the delete route to `post/form/{id}/delete` and have `post/form/{id}` as the show route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use 1 route for 2 methods.
The solution is using 1 method which fires concrete method eg.

routes.php

```
get('post/form/{id?}', 'PostConteoller@form');
```

PostController.php

```
public function form($id = null) {
    return $id ? $this->deleteForm($id) : $this->createForm();
}
```

However using 2 routes is much simpler.

Comment: It is what I want. it's working very well! thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by James this is not really practical but you could achieve this via the following.

Laravel gives you the possibility to define optional route parameters as shown below.

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
    return $name;
});

Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = 'John') {
    return $name;
});
```

Laravel Documentation about Route Parameters: [Laravel Route Parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters)

So this means you could just make your route like this.

```
Route::get('post/form/{id?}', array('as' => 'admin.post', 'uses' => "PostController@getForm"))
```

In your controller you then need to check if the 'id' is present. If not you create the user. If the 'id' is present you delete the user.